# Spring data, табличные связи

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data

Помогите со связями между таблицами! Задумка такая:

- есть юзер (табличка `user`)
- есть комната (табличка `room`)
- есть сообщение (табличка `message`)

Связи:

- юзер и комната - один ко многим;
- комната и сообщение - один ко многим;
- юзер и сообщение - один ко многим.

Каждый юзер может создать комнату, но это не обязательно, где будут обмениваться сообщениями другие пользователи и он в том же числе. Он может иметь несколько комнат, а комната только 1 создателя но в ней могут переписываться многие пользователи. Сообщение в свою очередь хранит ид комнаты и юзера, который отправил, а так же значение.

Проблема в том, что я не могу правильно сделать связи, точнее, как запрограммировать это на джаве в hibernate. Ниже код, прошу подскажите, как правильно реализовать связи.

User;

```
package ua.samuliak.messenger.entity;

import org.hibernate.annotations.GenericGenerator;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

@Entity
@Table(name = "\"user\"")
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "increment")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "increment", strategy = "increment")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "id_room")
    private Long room;

    @Column(nullable = false, length = 20)
    private String login;

    @Column(nullable = false, length = 20)
    private String password;

    @Column(length = 2)
    private String country;

    @Column(length = 2)
    private Integer age;

    @Column(length = 25)
    private String occupation;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user")
    private Set<Room> rooms = new HashSet<Room>();

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user_mes")
    private Set<Message> messages = new HashSet<Message>();


    public User() {}

    public User(String login, String password, String country) {
        this.login = login;
        this.password = password;
        this.country = country;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Long getRoom() {
        return room;
    }

    public void setRoom(Long room) {
        this.room = room;
    }

    public String getLogin() {
        return login;
    }

    public void setLogin(String login) {
        this.login = login;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getCountry() {
        return country;
    }

    public void setCountry(String country) {
        this.country = country;
    }

    public Integer getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(Integer age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    public String getOccupation() {
        return occupation;
    }

    public void setOccupation(String occupation) {
        this.occupation = occupation;
    }

//    public Set<Room> getRooms() {
//        return rooms;
//    }
//
//    public void setRooms(Set<Room> rooms) {
//        this.rooms = rooms;
//    }
}
```

P.S. в табличку user закоментировано 2 последние метода, так как выдает ошибку

Room:

```
package ua.samuliak.messenger.entity;

import org.hibernate.annotations.GenericGenerator;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

@Entity
@Table(name = "room")
public class Room {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "increment")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "increment", strategy = "increment")
    private Long id;

    @Column(nullable = false, length = 30)
    private String title;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
    private User user;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "room")
    private Set<Message> messages = new HashSet<Message>();



    public Room() {}

    public Room(String title, User user) {
        this.user = user;
        this.title = title;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public User getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    public void setUser(User user) {
        this.user = user;
    }
}
```

Message:

```
package ua.samuliak.messenger.entity;

import org.hibernate.annotations.GenericGenerator;

import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Table(name = "message")
public class Message {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "increment")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "increment", strategy = "increment")
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "room_id")
    private Room room;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
    private Room user_mes;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String value;


    public Message() {}

    public Message(Room room, String value) {
        this.room = room;
        this.value = value;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Room getRoom() {
        return room;
    }

    public void setRoom(Room room) {
        this.room = room;
    }

    public Room getUser_mes() {
        return user_mes;
    }

    public void setUser_mes(Room user_mes) {
        this.user_mes = user_mes;
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Вам явно не хватает еще одной таблички, в которой будут храниться пользователи залогиненные в комнату / чат. Предлагаю воспользоваться упрощенным примером проекта (ну, насколько я смог понять вашу идею). Я использовал **Spring Data** и **Spring Boot** для быстрого запуска приложения. Проект запускается командой `spring-boot:run`. [Код проекта на Github](https://github.com/mxbyrd/ruSO_answers/tree/master/spring-data-531907).

**pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>org.mxbyrd</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-data-531907</artifactId>
    <version>0.1.0</version>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.5.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <!-- DEPENDENCIES -->
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <!-- BUILD -->
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <!-- REPOSITORIES -->
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-releases</id>
            <name>Spring Releases</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>org.jboss.repository.releases</id>
            <name>JBoss Maven Release Repository</name>
            <url>https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/repositories/releases</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-releases</id>
            <name>Spring Releases</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>

</project>
```

**Сущности**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "\"user\"")
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "user_id")
    private Integer userID;

    private String name;

    public User() {}

    public User(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Integer getUserID() {
        return userID;
    }

    public void setUserID(Integer userID) {
        this.userID = userID;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        builder.append("User [userID=");
        builder.append(userID);
        builder.append(", name=");
        builder.append(name);
        builder.append("]");
        return builder.toString();
    }
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "room")
public class Room {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "room_id")
    private Integer roomID;

    private String name;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", nullable = false)
    private User owner;

    public Room() {}

    public Room(String name, User owner) {
        super();
        this.name = name;
        this.owner = owner;
    }

    public Integer getRoomID() {
        return roomID;
    }

    public void setRoomID(Integer roomID) {
        this.roomID = roomID;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public User getOwner() {
        return owner;
    }

    public void setOwner(User owner) {
        this.owner = owner;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        builder.append("Room [roomID=");
        builder.append(roomID);
        builder.append(", name=");
        builder.append(name);
        builder.append(", owner=");
        builder.append(owner);
        builder.append("]");
        return builder.toString();
    }
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "message")
public class Message {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "message_id")
    private Integer messageID;

    private String text;

    @Column(name = "creation_date")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date creationDate = new Date();

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", nullable = false)
    private User author;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "room_id", nullable = false)
    private Room thread;

    public Message() {}

    public Message(String text, User author, Room thread) {
        this.text = text;
        this.author = author;
        this.thread = thread;
    }

    public Integer getMessageID() {
        return messageID;
    }

    public void setMessageID(Integer messageID) {
        this.messageID = messageID;
    }

    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }

    public void setText(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }

    public Date getCreationDate() {
        return creationDate;
    }

    public void setCreationDate(Date creationDate) {
        this.creationDate = creationDate;
    }

    public User getAuthor() {
        return author;
    }

    public void setAuthor(User author) {
        this.author = author;
    }

    public Room getThread() {
        return thread;
    }

    public void setThread(Room thread) {
        this.thread = thread;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        builder.append("Message [messageID=");
        builder.append(messageID);
        builder.append(", text=");
        builder.append(text);
        builder.append(", creationDate=");
        builder.append(creationDate);
        builder.append(", author=");
        builder.append(author);
        builder.append(", thread=");
        builder.append(thread);
        builder.append("]");
        return builder.toString();
    }
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "presence")
public class Presence {

    // это composite key (составной ключ), который состоит
    // из 2-х ID - пользователя и комнаты
    @EmbeddedId
    private PresenceKey id;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date loggedTime = new Date();

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private User user;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "room_id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private Room room;

    public Presence() {}

    public Presence(PresenceKey id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public PresenceKey getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(PresenceKey id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Date getLoggedTime() {
        return loggedTime;
    }

    public void setLoggedTime(Date loggedTime) {
        this.loggedTime = loggedTime;
    }

    public User getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    public void setUser(User user) {
        this.user = user;
    }

    public Room getRoom() {
        return room;
    }

    public void setRoom(Room room) {
        this.room = room;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        builder.append("Presence [id=");
        builder.append(id);
        builder.append(", loggedTime=");
        builder.append(loggedTime);
        builder.append(", user=");
        builder.append(user);
        builder.append(", room=");
        builder.append(room);
        builder.append("]");
        return builder.toString();
    }
}

@Embeddable
public class PresenceKey implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Column(name = "room_id")
    private Integer roomID;

    @Column(name = "user_id")
    private Integer userID;

    public PresenceKey() {}

    public PresenceKey(User user, Room room) {
        this.userID = user.getUserID();
        this.roomID = room.getRoomID();
    }

    public Integer getRoomID() {
        return roomID;
    }

    public void setRoomID(Integer roomID) {
        this.roomID = roomID;
    }

    public Integer getUserID() {
        return userID;
    }

    public void setUserID(Integer userID) {
        this.userID = userID;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        builder.append("PresenceKey [roomID=");
        builder.append(roomID);
        builder.append(", userID=");
        builder.append(userID);
        builder.append("]");
        return builder.toString();
    }
}
```

**Репозитории**

```
public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<User, Integer> {
    User findByName(String name);
}

public interface RoomRepository extends CrudRepository<Room, Integer> {
    Room findByName(String name);
}

public interface MessageRepository extends CrudRepository<Message, Integer> {
    @Query("select m from Message m where room_id = ?1")
    List<Message> findAllByRoomID(Integer roomID);
}

public interface PresenceRepository extends CrudRepository<Presence, Integer> {
    @Query("select p from Presence p where room_id = ?1")
    List<Presence> findAllByRoomID(Integer roomID);
}
```

**Приложение**

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Application.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class);
    }

    @Bean
    public CommandLineRunner demo(UserRepository userRepo, RoomRepository roomRepo, PresenceRepository presenceRepo,
                    MessageRepository messageRepo) {
        return (args) -> {
            userRepo.save(new User("Philip J. Fry"));
            userRepo.save(new User("Bart Simpson"));
            userRepo.save(new User("Samurai Jack"));

            log.info("Смотрим какие пользователи у нас имеются:");
            log.info("-------------------------------");
            for ( User user : userRepo.findAll() ) {
                log.info(user.toString());
            }
            log.info("");

            log.info("Создаем чат:");
            log.info("-------------------------------");
            roomRepo.save(new Room("Talks", userRepo.findByName("Bart Simpson")));
            for ( Room room : roomRepo.findAll() ) {
                log.info(room.toString());
            }
            log.info("");

            log.info("Добавляем в чат пользователей:");
            log.info("-------------------------------");
            presenceRepo.save(new Presence(
                            new PresenceKey(userRepo.findByName("Bart Simpson"), roomRepo.findByName("Talks"))));
            presenceRepo.save(new Presence(
                            new PresenceKey(userRepo.findByName("Samurai Jack"), roomRepo.findByName("Talks"))));
            log.info("");

            log.info("Смотрим кто у нас сидит в чате:");
            log.info("-------------------------------");
            for ( Presence presence : presenceRepo.findAllByRoomID(roomRepo.findByName("Talks").getRoomID()) ) {
                log.info(userRepo.findOne(presence.getUser().getUserID()).toString());
            }
            log.info("");

            log.info("Общаемся:");
            log.info("-------------------------------");
            messageRepo.save(new Message("Всем привееееет! Ололо!", userRepo.findByName("Bart Simpson"),
                            roomRepo.findByName("Talks")));
            messageRepo.save(new Message("Гитлер капут!", userRepo.findByName("Samurai Jack"),
                            roomRepo.findByName("Talks")));
            log.info("");

            log.info("Смотрим кто кто отписался в чат:");
            log.info("-------------------------------");
            for ( Message message : messageRepo.findAllByRoomID(roomRepo.findByName("Talks").getRoomID()) ) {
                log.info(message.getAuthor().getName() + " пишет: " + message.getText());
            }
            log.info("");
        };
    }
}
```

**Вывод**

```
example.Application : Смотрим какие пользователи у нас имеются:
example.Application : -------------------------------
example.Application : User [userID=1, name=Philip J. Fry]
example.Application : User [userID=2, name=Bart Simpson]
example.Application : User [userID=3, name=Samurai Jack]
example.Application : 
example.Application : Создаем чат:
example.Application : -------------------------------
example.Application : Room [roomID=1, name=Talks, owner=User [userID=2, name=Bart Simpson]]
example.Application : 
example.Application : Добавляем в чат пользователей:
example.Application : -------------------------------
example.Application : 
example.Application : Смотрим кто у нас сидит в чате:
example.Application : -------------------------------
example.Application : User [userID=2, name=Bart Simpson]
example.Application : User [userID=3, name=Samurai Jack]
example.Application : 
example.Application : Общаемся:
example.Application : -------------------------------
example.Application : 
example.Application : Смотрим кто кто отписался в чат:
example.Application : -------------------------------
example.Application : Bart Simpson пишет: Всем привееееет! Ололо!
example.Application : Samurai Jack пишет: Гитлер капут!
```

Comment: Отлично!) Можете подсказать, почему использовали для GrudRepositories а не Jpa ?? Кстати, почему room и user связанны Один-К-Одному ??  P.S. залейте проект на гит плис

Comment: Используйте те абстракции, которые предоставляют методы необходимые для вашей бизнес логики. Я не использовал пагинацию и сортировку, поэтому хватило `CrudRepository`. Тоже самое со связями - незачем делать те, которыми не пользуешься. Ссылку на гит добавил.

Comment: Спасибо!) Помогли! Буду сейчас разбираться и редактировать проект